# Create an object with multiple keys that don't exist at once

Tags: javascript

How do you create a nested object with multiple keys that don't exist? Instead of creating them one by one.

For example:

```
const state = {};
state [a][b][c] = 5;
```

How do you do this instead of:

```
state[a] = {};
state[a][b]={};
state[a][b][c] = 5;
```

I want to do this because `state[a][b]` may have others keys in it and I don't want to delete them. I only want to change the `c` key. But if there is no other key, then create it like this.

So state could also be:

```
state {
    a: {
        b: {
            x: 20,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop keys. if it's not exist - create with new object, else continue iteration until all keys executed, on last key assign value

Comment: you could use `lodash/set` which does exactly this

Comment: If ```a, b``` have other keys in them then your first method should work. If they don't then you won't be overwriting anything.

Comment: @thedude Thank you. This helped me and it's easy to use. I don't have any problem using it although I would have hoped that there was a native way in javascript to do this, without iterating on the object or something else. Like in php: I could easily do `state[a][b][c] = 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The only way is create a loop and then assign one by one:

```js
function set(state, path, value) {
            var pList = path.split('.');
            var len = pList.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
                var elem = pList[i];
                if (!state[elem]) state[elem] = {}
                state = state[elem];
            }

            state[pList[len - 1]] = value;

            return state;
}
const state = {};
set(state, 'a.b.c', 5);

console.log(state);
```

Comment: @Roland There is no need to add other `js` library  you can write a simple method that does the same thing for you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `hasOwnProperty` in this way:

```
if (!state.hasOwnProperty(a)) state[a] = {};
if (!state[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) state[a][b] = {};
if (!state[a][b].hasOwnProperty(c)) state[a][b][c] = {};
state[a][b][c] = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
const obj =  { "a" : { "b" : { "c" : 5 } } };
console.log( obj.a.b.c );
```